# Jackson WRAP_ROOT_VALUE adds two root elements

Tags: java, json, serialization, playframework, jackson

I'm writing a REST API in Java and Play Framework, however I ran into a problem with Jackson serialization. I have the following model:

```
@Entity
@JsonRootName("country")
public class Country extends BaseModel<Country> {
    private String name;
    private Collection<City> cities;

    ...
}
```

The Jackson object mapper configuration:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = Json.newDefaultMapper()
                .configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true)
                .configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
```

When I serialize a Country model however,

```
Country c = service.get(id);
return ok(toJson(c));
```

I get the following output:

```
{
  "ObjectNode" : {
    "country" : {
      "id" : 5,
      "name" : "Holandija",
      "cities" : [ ]
    }
  }
}
```

The expected output would be:

```
{
    "country" : {
      "id" : 5,
      "name" : "Holandija",
      "cities" : [ ]
    }
}
```

Why is Jackson adding the extra ObjectNode node? How to get rid of it?

Comment: .configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false) tried this? @mobster1930

Comment: @Sreemat No, this removes both the ObjectNode and country element.

Comment: can post you expect output

Comment: @Sreemat I've added it to the question now.

Comment: What is your return type of your method ?is it Result? @mobster1930

Comment: @Sreemat Yes, it is, but I don't see why would that matter?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a problem in toJson method. The following code works perfect (the original class Country was modified for simplicity):

```
@Entity
@JsonRootName(value = "country")
public class Country {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public Collection<String> cities;   
    public Country() {
    }   
    public Country(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void testRootJsonMapping() throws JsonProcessingException {
    Country tested = new Country(55, "Neverland");   
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true)
            .configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(tested);
    System.out.println("json:" + json);
}
```

Test output:

```
json:{
    "country" : {
        "id" : 55,
        "name" : "Neverland",
        "cities" : null
    }
}
```

If json conversion is done with Play API Json, it should be configured on startup with appropriate mapping options:

```
 private void configureJson() {  
       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()  
           .configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true)  
           .configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
       Json.setObjectMapper(mapper);  
 }
```

[Here](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/07/customizing-json-mapping-in-play.html) you can read more details of how to customize Json conversion in Play.

Comment: Doesn't work either, the output is the as in the original post :/

Comment: I put more details in the answer

Comment: Doesn't work again. It must be something with Play's toJson() method in that case. Thanks for help though.